# How to check the existence of Kafka topic in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I am currently working with Nodejs and Kafka whereby a Nodejs server is set up to receive events and the data corresponding to the events are sent to Kafka. In Kafka, producer will create a topic accordingly and dynamically, if topic does not exist already. To do that, I want to check the existence of the topic, if it exists or not before creation.

I am currently using kafka-node module for kafka-node integrated functionalities. However, I could not find out any functionality which either tells about the existence of the topic or returns the list of all the topics currently exist in kafka.

On searching on Internet, I found kafka-rest proxy which does help to know  about this by fetching the current topics but I did not understand how to put that to use much.

Is there any other API via which I can achieve the stated functionality above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do both at the same time, actually. Just use the undocumented `Client.loadMetadataForTopics()` function. Like this:

```
var kafka = require('kafka-node');
var client = new kafka.Client("localhost:2181");

client.loadMetadataForTopics(["NonExistentTopic"], (err, resp) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(resp))
});

// [{"0":{"nodeId":0,"host":"host-001","port":9092}},{"error":["LeaderNotAvailable"],"metadata":{}}]
```

See the `LeaderNotAvailable` error? That means the topic doesn't exist. But -- assuming `auto.topic.create.enable` is set to `true`, then the call to `loadMetadataForTopics` will also create the topic. So you get both in one call -- if you get the `error`, then the topic didn't exist and was created, if you don't get the error you get the actual topic metadata.

Comment: Thank you. This looks close to what I was looking for :)

Comment: Any idea how to do the same thing using `kafka.ConsumerGroup`?